# Slow insert when using @SecondaryTable with hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

When I use a secondary table, saving the entities takes 2 times the time it takes without a secondary table.

However, the inserts to the secondary table (postgresql) takes less than 1ms according to postgres logs. So, I guess it's something with hibernate itself. Is there any known performance issue with secondary tables in hibernate? I'm using hibernate 2.1

Comment: Wow, you are using a Hibernate version that is approximately 20 years old and you are asking if there are known performance problems? You should maybe update your server from Pentium 2 to Pentium 4 first before measuring the performance again :D Kidding aside, I don't think anybody can or will help you with such old software.